0% Pay Rise this year, following large profits
My employer has stated that because I am in the 75th percentile for salary, industry-wide, for my position: I will be getting a zero percent pay rise.
Not 75th percentile in my company. But, industry-wide. I work in customer support, which is at the lower end of pay for our company, anyway.
Therefore, I will receive no pay rise this year.
As I am not getting any increase in pay and remuneration - can I discuss this zero percent pay rise with colleagues?

This is either a company policy question, or a legal question. Either is really out of scope here.

If you are unhappy with your pay, why don’t you find, a different job? Are you able to confirm you are paid in the 75% percentile?

Does the company normally give a raise to match the inflation rate in your country?

Your salary is the fee the company pays to retain you on their staff. If the fee they offer isn't high enough, you don't have to stay retained.

You can absolutely discuss this with your colleagues. Better yet, you can discuss this with other companies.

This is a crap thing to do to you.  Perhaps a case could be made if you were in the 110 percentile, but at 75 there is room to grow.  Move on, they hate their employees.


can I discuss this zero percent pay rise with colleagues?

Of course you can. It's not clear that this will help anything, other than make you feel better.
But if you think you deserve more, and your current company won't give you more, you should find a new job and leave this one.
If your company is right, there are other companies out there who might pay you more.

You can certainly discuss it on your own time. Discussing it on company time may or may not have consequences depending on local law, company policy, how you discuss it, whether management thinks you are trying to organize a group protest or union...
The company is certainly less likely to give a raise in years that it is less profitable. But profit does not guarantee a raise. The company may invest the money elsewhere. Or they may give a raise to the people who they think most deserve it, or who they particularly want to retain. You have told us what percentile they are saying your pay is in; you have not told us what percentile they say your productivity is in.
If you want to be paid more, ask your manager what they need to see from you in order to support them suggesting that you be paid more. Meeting those goals won't guarantee a raise either, but is more likely to get you one than simply complaining.
If customer support is at the low end of your company's pay scale, perhaps you should ask what it would take to move into one of the areas which pays better. Then invest in acquiring and demonstrating those skills. Pro tip: the difficulty of moving between departments is often proportional to how high you have to go in the management tree to find the common point where one manager has responsibility for both jobs.
If all else fails, look for a better paying job elsewhere. But don't quit your current job until you have a signed offer and a starting date for the new job in your hand.
Don't just complain about it. Find out how to do something about it. Then do that.

In germany you can discuss your pay with others, even if contract clauses state you may not. Those clauses are void. Courts have ruled that dicsussing pay with others is the only way for employees to gain the information they need to have fair negotiations with their employers and you cannot sign this right away.

As I am not getting any increase in pay and remuneration - can I discuss this zero percent pay rise with colleagues?

So the answer is yes you can, in your own private time. You can be disciplined for discussing it on work time however, just as you can be disciplined for doing anything that isn't work while you are on the clock.

The only country where discussing Salary is actively discouraged is the US...
However, discussing your salary is protected I believe under the 1st Amendment.
If you are uncomfortable though, plausible deniability is your friend.

It is actually protected by the National Labor Relations Act (NLRA) https://www.nlrb.gov/about-nlrb/rights-we-protect/your-rights/your-rights-to-discuss-wages.  I doubt the US is the only country on Earth where employers would prefer you not discuss salary though it is an outlier compared to most countries in Europe

Thanks for the clarification. Could have sworn it was a 1A issue but maybe I'm getting confused.

@TheDemonLord - What does the 1A have to do with talking about compensation for a job?

Protected speech. You can't be fired from a job for political beliefs (protected speech), and my memory is that discussion of your personal affairs fell under the umbrella of protected speech

@TheDemonLord—I would say that is a stretch. Protected speech applies primarily to the state or federal government, not to a private or even public entity; different states will extend specific rights to employees in this regard.

1A has nothing to do with jobs, unless you work for the government. "Free Speech" doesn't mean you can say whatever you want with no consequences. It just means the government won't come after you for it.

Oh well, looks like I was wrong on that. Oops.
